# Google Script return value from one sheet to another sheet

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

This is my first Google Script and I'm struggling a little bit while trying to bring back the values from a specific cell & sheet to another sheet.

I have a total of 18 columns, being the first one the ID which is going to be the input that the user would need to add in order to retrieve the data from one sheet to another. As the first one is the ID, and will be already be inputted by the user, I would need to retrieve the data from columns 2 to 18
Here is my code:

```
function SearchID() {
  var columnIndex = 0;
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var formS = ss.getSheetByName("Manual Costs App"); // App sheet

  var str = formS.getRange("D6").getValue(); // The ID to search will be inputted here
  var dataS = ss.getSheetByName("Inputs").getDataRange().getValues(); // Retrieving the data based on the user input
  for (var i = 0; i<=dataS.length; i++) {
    var row = dataS[i];
    if (row[columnIndex] == str) {
      formS.getRange("D9").setValue(row[1]);
      formS.getRange("D13").setValue(row[2]);
      formS.getRange("D14").setValue(row[3]);
      formS.getRange("D15").setValue(row[4]);
      formS.getRange("D16").setValue(row[5]);
      formS.getRange("D18").setValue(row[6]);
      formS.getRange("D19").setValue(row[7]);
      formS.getRange("D20").setValue(row[8]);
      formS.getRange("D21").setValue(row[9]);
      formS.getRange("D22").setValue(row[10]);
      formS.getRange("D23").setValue(row[11]);
      formS.getRange("D25").setValue(row[12]);
      formS.getRange("D26").setValue(row[13]);
      formS.getRange("D27").setValue(row[14]);
      formS.getRange("D28").setValue(row[15]);
      formS.getRange("D29").setValue(row[16]);
      formS.getRange("D30").setValue(row[17]);
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

The link to a sample spreadsheet of what I'm building is [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11zlovigfElj1q8JQslIMJQ9SeU-o-v41wmpNCtz3JCY/edit?usp=sharing)

**Update**: Everything is fixed now! What I did was removing the space in the for loop. After that, it retrieved the data but a `TypeError: Cannot read property '0'`. Also solved it adding a `break` after the loop to avoid it.

Comment: I would think this could be done very simply using one VLOOKUP(), is there a reason you are not going with that?

Comment: Hey @MattKing, thanks for your response. Ideally, this SearchID function is going to be optional in case they want to retrieve an specific ID and update any of the different fields. Note that, the values will be set in the same exact cells from where they inputed them, cells that have data validation to avoid adding bad entries. Maybe I could retrieve the data to another column, instead of the same one, and input the edits from the 2nd column, although, if possible, I would like to avoid duplications and have everything in the same fields

Comment: As per the last update, if you have managed to solve it, can you insert the solution as an answer so more people can benefit from it?

Comment: @Kessy I have already replaced the old code for the most updated one

Answer (score 0):

It's a type in your `for` loop, notice how spelled `length`:

```js
for (var i = 1; i <= values.lenght; i++)
```

You also don't want to set values line by line like you do, get a longer range and set the values with `setValues()` rather than `setValue()`. There's quite a bit of refactoring to do there actually.

Comment: Thanks @Dmitry. Nevertheless, looking at the ```for``` loop that you shared with me, this is exactly how I have it already and still doesn't work. Might it be something else? Regarding the ```setValues()```, any ideas on how to improve it? I don't know javascript, so I guess it's easy that my code could be easily improved

Comment: To be honest with you, your code needs to be fully re-written. If you can, share a sample spreadsheet conataining a sheet with the starting data and a sheet with your expected result. Also @MattKing asked you a good question.

Comment: Hey Dmitry, I will update the post with some sample of what I'm building. Also, I will include in the spreadsheet, in case you can see it, my whole code

Answer (score 0):

The user did found the answer and updated it on the question.

Posting here as community wiki so it can be seen more clearly.

**User's answer:**

Update: Everything is fixed now! What I did was removing the space in the for loop. After that, it retrieved the data but a TypeError: Cannot read property '0'. Also solved it adding a break after the loop to avoid it.

```
function SearchID() {
  var columnIndex = 0;
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var formS = ss.getSheetByName("Manual Costs App"); // App sheet

  var str = formS.getRange("D6").getValue(); // The ID to search will be inputted here
  var dataS = ss.getSheetByName("Inputs").getDataRange().getValues(); // Retrieving the data based on the user input
  for (var i = 0; i<=dataS.length; i++) {
    var row = dataS[i];
    if (row[columnIndex] == str) {
      formS.getRange("D9").setValue(row[1]);
      formS.getRange("D13").setValue(row[2]);
      formS.getRange("D14").setValue(row[3]);
      formS.getRange("D15").setValue(row[4]);
      formS.getRange("D16").setValue(row[5]);
      formS.getRange("D18").setValue(row[6]);
      formS.getRange("D19").setValue(row[7]);
      formS.getRange("D20").setValue(row[8]);
      formS.getRange("D21").setValue(row[9]);
      formS.getRange("D22").setValue(row[10]);
      formS.getRange("D23").setValue(row[11]);
      formS.getRange("D25").setValue(row[12]);
      formS.getRange("D26").setValue(row[13]);
      formS.getRange("D27").setValue(row[14]);
      formS.getRange("D28").setValue(row[15]);
      formS.getRange("D29").setValue(row[16]);
      formS.getRange("D30").setValue(row[17]);
      break;
    }
  }
}
```